# Parametric equations of manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds, parametric

I have am working for a linear algebra test and I realized that I don't know how to solve exercises with linear manifolds even the basic one.

W : $
 x+y-z+u=1
$

$
 2x+u=2
$

$
 z -u=0
$

I don't understand how I am supposed to get the parametric equation of that manifold. Can you help me please?

Comment: 1) From the last equation, you see $z$ depends on $u$. 2) From the second equation, you see $x$ depends on $u$. 3) From the first equation and the two previous points, you see $y$ depends on $u$ too. Hence the set $W$ can be parametrized by a single parameter $u$ with $$u\mapsto \left( \dfrac{2-u}{2}+1,\dfrac{2-u}{2},u,u\right)$$

Comment: @Zircht Then we find $x=\frac{2-u}{u}$ so why is the first value $x=\frac{2-u}{u}+1$ ?

Comment: Ups, I swapped the first two, sorry.

Comment: @Zircht Thank you a lot now I understand. I think there is also a mistake for the second value. It should be $u$ right? because $y=1-x=1-1+u=u$.

Comment: Where? $y=1-x$ and $x=\frac{2-u}{2}$ (so there's a minus sign missing in my comment ( _sigh_ )) but I don't see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, to be safe, write the linear system as $Ax=0$ then find a basis for $Null(A) = \{ x | Ax=0 \}$. The span of the basis is essentially the patch for the linear manifold.

For example, $x+y+z+u=0$ and $x-u-z=0$ so $A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 \end{array} \right]$. We calculate, 
$$\text{rref}(A|0) = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c} 1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 0\end{array} \right] $$
Traditionally, I use $z,u$ as parameters, but some insist we write $z=s$ and $u=t$ so I'll play along, note row one gives $x = z+u$ and row 2 gives $y=-2z-2u$ hence 
$$X(s,t) = ( s+t, -2s-2t, s, t) $$
This parametrizes the plane defined by the set of equations I gave.

Of course, for simple examples adding equations etc... wins, but, beware the problem of dependent equations. Row reduction is the natural enemy of the hidden clone equation.